# how zero is affecting the result in division method

Tags: java

```
int a=0234;
int result=a/100;
System.out.println("result is " + result);
```

output:

> result is 1

Why is `result` not `2`?

Comment: Try `System.out.println("a is "+a);` and it'll be obvious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `0234` is an `Octal` number.

When you append a zero in front of a numeric constant, Java treats it as an [Octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) number.

If you convert it to decimal number system, then it equals to `156`, dividing which by decimal `100` results 1 (due to integer division).

Answer (score 7):

`0234` is an [octal number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) which equals `2 * 82 + 3 * 81 +  4 * 80`, which is `156`.

Then 156/100 = 1 (due to [integer division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html))

Answer (score 2):

That's a literal octal integer. So `0234` in decimal is 156, not 234.

After that, your code does an integer division, so 156 / 100 = 1.

More info:

- [Java Primitive Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). Check Integer Literals.

Answer (score 2):

`0234` is an octal number, and is equal to 156. Integer division rules then perform truncation for a result of 1. Please see [JLS 3.10.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1):

> An octal numeral consists of an ASCII digit 0 followed by one or more of the ASCII digits 0 through 7 interspersed with underscores, and can represent a positive, zero, or negative integer.

Answer (score 1):

Integer literals that start with 0 are interpreted as octal, not decimal numbers. So `0234` is actually octal for 156 decimal. Hence 156/100 = 1 in integer division.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare an int starts with 0 and not contains any digit greater than 7 java consider it as a octal number. 
Therefore 0236 is actually 236 base 8 which is 156
Then 156/100 = 1